# How to work with binary tree in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree, addition

I have a program where I have a binary tree, represented as a structure with two pointers and a root. I then want to enter n elements (denoted by the br variable) as values of the nodes of the tree. Then I enter these elements using the `add(param1,...)` function. However when I press return key, after I have entered all of them, the program crashes. I would like to ask why this happens?

```
// TreeGraph.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct elem {
    char key;
    elem *left, *right;
} *root = NULL;
void add(int n, elem * &t);
int num,br,i;
int main()
{
    cout << "Въведете брой елементи\n";
    cin >> br;
    cout << "Въведете стойнсотите на листата на дървото\n";
    while (i != br) {
    cin >> num;
    add(num, root);
    i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
void add(int n, elem * &t) {
    if (t) {
        t = new elem;
        t->key = n;
        t->left = t->right = NULL;
    }
    else {
        if (t->key < n)
            add(n, t->right);
        else
            add(n, t->left);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Asesh • `i` is a global, so it gets initialized to zero.

Comment: Another issue, not related to the question, is that the elem has `char key`, but add is using `int n`.  Probably should change elem to have `int key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not an infinite loop. You are dereferencing a null pointer, so the program crashes.

In this code:

```
void add(int n, elem * &t) {
    if (t) {
        t = new elem;
        t->key = n;
        t->left = t->right = NULL;
    }
    else {
        if (t->key < n)
            add(n, t->right);
        else
            add(n, t->left);
    }
}
```

Your condition for adding the node is incorrect. It should be `if (!t)`. The location of a new node in a binary search tree must be as the child of a node with at least one null child pointer. To add the node, you need the recursion to get to one of these null pointers and then add the node there.

Think about what happens when you pass the initially-null root to the `add` function. The condition in the first `if` statement is false, so when you try to check the condition `if (t->key < n)`, you are attempting to access the `key` field of a non-existent object.